# Understanding the difference between Renderer and RootRenderer in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm writing a WebGL Custom Renderer in Angular2 as a component.  Can anyone help me better understand the distinction between RootRenderer vs Renderer?  If I want to have a component which uses its own renderer while the rest of the application still used the DomRenderer do I just specify my CustomRenderer as the class to use in the providers list?

```
{provide: Renderer, useClass: NodeGraphRenderer}
```

I'm finding that the only way I can get the Renderer to work is by using a CustomRootRenderer as well.  And only at the @NgModule level.  Does a custom renderer always have to have a custom root renderer to work?